# ¿Cómo contar el número de meses que aparace en esta lista?

Tags: javascript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Hola a toda la comunidad, como puedo contar el numero de meses por ejemplo tengo esta lista:

08-09-2021 
08-09-2021 
09-10-2021 
09-10-2021 
09-10-2021 
09-10-2021
09-10-2021 
09-10-2021
09-10-2021
09-10-2021

lo que necesito es saber como contar la cantidad de meses que aparecen por ejemplo; 09 que me aparezca 2 y que el 10 me apararezca 8

Agradezco la ayuda amigos

```
function sumarMeses (fecha)  {
  let contarMeses = new Date(fecha).getMonth()
  return contarMeses
}


let resultado = sumarMeses('08-09-2021','08-09-2021', '09-10-2021','09-10-2021','09-10-2021')

console.log(resultado)
```

Comment: Hola, la pregunta del millón, tienes la data así mismo? como la muestras en la pantalla? un array? un list? que haz intentado? cuales son tus avances?

Comment: Esa informacion la tiene guardad en una tabla de una base de datos o de donde la extrae?

Comment: Solo necesito contar el numero de meses que aparece y convertirlo y hacerle un parseInt para tener el número de meses que aparece

Comment: Coloca tu código y no una imagen para así ayudarte mejor

Comment: Y ya tu tienes las fechas cargadas en la lista?

Comment: por si me quiere hechar una mano https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/513071/148913

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer un mapa de meses y asignarles el conteo

```js
const meses = [
    '08-09-2021',
    '08-09-2021',
    '09-10-2021',
    '09-10-2021',
    '09-10-2021',
    '09-10-2021',
    '09-10-2021',
    '09-10-2021',
    '09-10-2021',
    '09-10-2021',
];

const contarMeses = {};

meses.forEach(mes => {
    const _mes = new Date(mes).getMonth() + 1;
    contarMeses[_mes] = contarMeses[_mes] ? contarMeses[_mes]+1 : 1;
});
console.log( contarMeses );
```

Comment: hola amigo eres un crack gracias por tu buena lógica.
amigo una pregunta referente a este código:
como uno hace para nada mas obtener valor y convertirlo a un dato de tipo Int

te muestro como lo estoy haciendo si esta bien 

  parseInt(Object.values(contarMeses)) 
necesito de este codigo 
{
  "8": 2, // nada mas los valores y que sea de tipo numerico
  "9": 8 ,
}

Comment: Hey, que bueno que te sirvió, para mantener la armonía del foro, recomiendo que hagas la respectiva pregunta en otro hilo, puesto que este está resuelto. (Aún esté ligado). Con gusto te apoyo si pones más información de lo que estas haciendo y qué resultado esperas.

Answer (score 0):

```
function contarMeses (listaMeses)
{
   var meses = new Array(12);
   var mes = 0;
   
   for (var i = 0; i < listaMeses.length; i++) 
   {
      mes = listaMeses[i].getUTCMonth();
      meses[mes] = meses[mes] + 1;
   }

   for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) 
   {
      if (meses[i] > 0)
      {
         console.log(i + 1 + ": " + meses[i]);
      }
   }
}
```

Se crea una función que recibe como parámetro tu lista de fechas, dentro de esta función se crea un arreglo de **12** posiciones simulando así los **12** meses del año, posteriormente se ejecuta un **ciclo for** que recorrerá tu lista de fechas y por cada fecha obtendrá su correspondiente mes a través de la **función getUTCMonth** y entonces en la correspondiente posición del **arreglo meses** (la posición seria el mes obtenido de la fecha) se incrementará en 1, de esta forma vamos contando la cantidad de veces que aparece determinado mes.

Al terminar este **ciclo for** se ejecutará entonces otro **ciclo for** que recorrerá el arreglo meses, mostrando de esta forma la cantidad de veces que se repite un mes.

Revisa bien este código y adáptalo a tus necesidades.