# ¿Cómo convertir la clave de un objecto en un entero?

Tags: javascript, json

Cómo obtener las clave y convertir a entero?

```
    function contarMeses(listaMeses) {
      const claves = []
      const contarMeses = {};
      for(let mes of listaMeses){
        const numMese = new Date(mes).getMonth() + 1;
    contarMeses[numMese] = contarMeses[numMese] ? contarMeses[numMese] + 1 :1;
      }
       
      let keys = Object.values(contarMeses)
    
      keys.forEach((clave) => {
        let entero = parseInt(clave)
         claves.push(entero)
        
      })
      return claves
    
    }
    
    
    
    let resultado = contarMeses(meses)
    console.log( resultado)
```

Comment: no entiendo, supongo que el objeto que quieres es contarMeses, pero a qué clave haces referencia?

Comment: js automaticamente lo pasa a string porque es una llave no un indice... pero igual no es necesario pasarla a entero si puedes acceder a ella con `contarMeses[9]` y el resultado sera igual a  `contarMeses["9"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te arroja NaN porque tienes la fecha en un formato dd-mm-aaaa que Date no acepta.

Para que puedas conseguir lo que deseas primero debes convertir la fecha a un formato que Date acepte, como aaaa/mm/dd.

Si pruebas este código obtendras las keys en un array y a partir de allí puedes manipularlas como quieras:

```js
 const meses = [
   '08-09-2021',
   '08-09-2021',
   '09-10-2021',
   '09-10-2021',
   '09-10-2021',
   '09-10-2021',
   '09-10-2021',
   '09-10-2021',
   '09-10-2021',
   '09-10-2021',
 ];

 const contarMeses = {};

 meses.forEach(mes => {
   fechajs = mes.split('-').reverse().join('/');
   const _mes = new Date(fechajs).getMonth() + 1;
   contarMeses[_mes] = contarMeses[_mes] ? contarMeses[_mes] + 1 : 1;
 });

 arr = Object.keys(contarMeses)

 arr.forEach(clave => {
   entero = parseInt(clave)
   console.log(typeof entero)
 });
```